# How to place two image() plots into one?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to add two image() plots in one by doing something like that:

```
p1 <- image(something)
p2 <- image(something)

library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(lattice)
grid.arrange(p1,p2,ncol = 2)
```

Sadly, this doesn't work.
Maybe someone has a hint.

Comment: ggplot2.multiplot from easyGgplot2 could help

Comment: How about `par(mfrow =c(1,2))`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of arranging two images in one row/two columns:

```
x <- y <- seq(-2*pi, 2*pi, len = 27)
r <- sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+"))
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
i1 <- image(z = z <- sin(r^2)*exp(-r/6), col  = gray((0:32)/32))
i2 <- image(z = z <- cos(r^42)*exp(-r/6), col  = gray((0:32)/32))
```

The important part is the `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` which alines the following plots or images (`i1` and `i2`). 
The above code produces the following image:

[image: Resulting plots in one row]

Note: Image example taken from the [offical R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/image.html)